Wigner function of Lorentzian
I am looking to see if I correctly evaluated this integral given the less than intuitive solution I found, which suggests to me something went awry. In short, I am looking to evaluate the Wigner function of a modified Lorentzian function. The function is written as
$$ f(q)= A \frac{\sigma^2}{4q^2+\sigma^2}$$
where A denotes some complex peak amplitude and $\sigma>0$ denotes the FWHM of the function $f(q)$. The definition of the Wigner function that I am using is as follows,
$$W_f(q,p) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f^*\left( q - \frac{q^\prime}{2} \right) f\left( q + \frac{q^\prime}{2} \right) e^{-iKq^\prime p} dq^\prime$$
where $K \in \mathbb{R}$. Substituting $f(q)$ into the above definition,
$$ W_f(q,p) = \frac{|A|^2\sigma^4}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-iKq^\prime p}}{\left(4 \left[ q - q^\prime/2 \right]^2+\sigma^2 \right) \left( 4\left[ q + q^\prime/2 \right]^2+\sigma^2 \right)} dq^\prime. $$
If we simplify the denominator, we find it can be written as a biquadratic in $q^\prime$,
$$ W_f(q,p) = \frac{|A|^2\sigma^4}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-iKq^\prime p}}{(q^\prime)^4+(2\sigma^2 - 8q^2)(q^\prime)^2+(\sigma^2+4q^2)^2} dq^\prime. $$
If we then decompose the Wigner transform Kernel into its constituent cosine and sine components, we obtain
$$ W_f(q,p) = \frac{|A|^2\sigma^4}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos{(Kq^\prime p)} -i\sin{(Kq^\prime p)}}{(q^\prime)^4+(2\sigma^2 - 8q^2)(q^\prime)^2+(\sigma^2+4q^2)^2} dq^\prime. $$
Given that the denominator is an even function and sine is an odd function, the portion of the integral related to sine will have an odd integrand with symmetric bounds, therefore this contribution is exactly zero. This allows us to modify the above to
$$ W_f(q,p) = \frac{|A|^2\sigma^4}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos{(Kq^\prime p)}}{(q^\prime)^4+(2\sigma^2 - 8q^2)(q^\prime)^2+(\sigma^2+4q^2)^2} dq^\prime. $$
The denominator can be factored to yield a product of four linear complex terms,
$$ W_f(q,p) = \frac{|A|^2\sigma^4}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos{(Kq^\prime p)}}{(q^\prime - [2q + i\sigma])(q^\prime - [2q - i\sigma])(q^\prime - [-2q + i\sigma])(q^\prime - [-2q - i\sigma])} dq^\prime. $$
Consider now the following contour, where by arguments of complex analysis,
$$W_f(q,p) = \oint - \int_\cap = 2\pi i \sum_{j \in C} \mathrm{Res}(z_j) - \int_\cap $$
where $z_j$ are the simple poles contained within the closed contour $C$. First tackling the semi-circle integral, this can be rewritten as
$$\int_\cap = \frac{i |A|^2\sigma^4}{2\pi} \lim_{R \, \rightarrow \, \infty} \int_0^\pi \frac{ R e^{i \theta} \cos \left( Kp R e^{i \theta} \right)}{R^4 e^{i 4 \theta} + (2 \sigma^2 - 8 q^2) R^2 e^{i 2\theta} + (\sigma^2 + 4 q^2)^2} d \theta. $$
By Jordan's Lemma,
$$\int_\cap = 0. $$
Thus, the we conclude that
$$ W_f(q,p) = 2\pi i \sum_{j \in C} \mathrm{Res}(z_j).$$
Only the poles $z=2q+i\sigma$ and $z=-2q+i\sigma$ are contained within the contour, for which if we evaluate their residues, we obtain
$$ \mathrm{Res}(2q+i\sigma) =  \frac{\cos(4Kqp+i2Kp\sigma)}{8iq\sigma(4q+2i\sigma)},$$
$$ \mathrm{Res}(-2q+i\sigma) =  \frac{\cos(4Kqp-i2Kp\sigma)}{8iq\sigma(4q-2i\sigma)}.$$
Substituting these back into the expression for $W_f$, we find that upon full simplification that
$$ W_f (q,p) = \frac{|A|^2 \sigma^3}{8q(4q^2+\sigma^2)} \left[ 2 q \cos(4Kqp) \cosh(2Kp \sigma) - \sigma \sin(4Kpq) \sinh(2Kp\sigma) \right]. $$
As is plain to see, the solution diverges due to the presence of the hyperbolic trigonometric functions. However, the Wigner function definition provided above can be shown to have the following identity,
$$|f(q)|^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} W_f(q,p) dp. $$
My question is then, do these regions of ever increasing growth somehow undergo cancellation of areas to recover the magnitude squared of $f(q)$, or have I made some error(s) in the derivation?

Your solution is not correct. Integrating $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos (Kpq')}{f(q'^2)}dq'$ in the complex plane you close the contour in such a way that the integral along a big circle $\to0$ as the radius $R\to0$. You either take $\cos(Kpq')=\Re, e^{iKPq'}$ and close the contour in the upped half-plane, or take $\cos(Kpq')=\frac{e^{iKPq'}+e^{-iKPq'}}2$ and consider two integrals, closing countours in the upper and lower half-plane correspondingly.

@Svyatoslav Thank you! You are exactly right that I was mistreating the cosine term. I decided to ignore my original idea of splitting the kernel and upon doing so, the problem became far easier to solve. I also noticed that you need to split the solution into two cases of when $\omega > 0$ or when $\omega < 0$. Upon doing so, it allows for proper treatment of using Jordan's Lemma to solve the problem. Once again, thank you for the help!

For those who were curious for the solution, if you follow the suggestion given by @Svyatoslav and do not decompose the kernel of the transformation, the solution is given as
$$ W_f(q,p) = \frac{|A|^2 \sigma^3 e^{-\sigma |K p|}}{8 q (4q^2 + \sigma^2)} \Big[ 2 q \cos (2q |K p|) + \sigma \sin (2 q | K p|) \Big].$$
